# detect superfluous zero bytes with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

in eac3to, when encoding an audio file (usually from a TrueHD source), it can detect if the audio is actually 16 bit, despite being stored as 24 bit. is it possible to detect this in ffmpeg instead? ive had a look through the documentation but i didnt see anything that would do this, but i may have missed something.

example of eac3to output with superfluous bytes:

```
eac3to v3.34
command line: eac3to  audio.thd audio.flac
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TrueHD, 2.0 channels, 48kHz, dialnorm: -27dB
Removing TrueHD dialog normalization...
Decoding with libav/ffmpeg...
Encoding FLAC with libFlac...
Creating file "audio.flac"...
The original audio track has a constant bit depth of 16 bits.
Superfluous zero bytes detected, will be stripped in 2nd pass.
Starting 2nd pass...
Decoding FLAC...
Reducing depth from 24 to 16 bits...
Encoding FLAC with libFlac...
Creating file "audio.flac"...
The processed audio track has a constant bit depth of 16 bits.
eac3to processing took 1 minute, 37 seconds.
Done.
```

file info from ffprobe:

```
"Input #0, truehd, from 'audio.thd': Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A Stream #0:0: Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)"
```

Comment: Share the readout of `ffmpeg -i audio.thd`

Comment: @Gyan "Input #0, truehd, from 'audio.thd':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **complete** readout.